# Mapping and converting column names to variables in json format in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fetching values from a database table (client). I am interested in two columns (first_name and id). Since I am sending the response as a json format, I would like to achieve a result like this

students: `["first_name": "adam", id:"12", ....]`

I tried `Student.all.map{|s| [s.first_name, s.id]}` but here I just get the values`(adam, 12)` not the indexes `("first_name", "id")`

is there a way to make the column name appear in the response without complicating the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less magic, then [mohamed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32827510/1426097), just using basic tools:

```
@students.map{|st| {id: st.id, first_name: st.first_name}}
```

Comment: yeah less magic, but it ignores the escaping overhead of json that's why I prefer it :d

Answer (score 1):

You can use only with json:

```
Student.all.to_json(:only=>[:id, :first_name])
```

That will work if you not overriding `as_json` or `to_json` in student model

Comment: thnks mate the resulte is good, but dimakura's answer looks a bit better

Comment: ok, but if you talking about json then do it in json and if you need scape use as_json, you don't have to foramt the json yourself.